# Beginning of Chopin nocturne no.20: slur and tie confusion

Tags: theory, piano, notation, chopin

In the opening bars of this c-sharp minor nocturne, we have the famous descending scales that are played twice, first in piano then in pianissimo. Here's a snapshot ([source](http://www.free-scores.com/partitions_telecharger.php?partition=43903)) of the part in question:
[image]

---

**Question:**
The lower curved line connecting the two *c sharps* of the right hand, (i.e. between the 2nd and 3rd chords of right hand, similarly between 4th and 5th chords), does this line correspond to a [**slur**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slur_(music)) in which case the two chords are played in a legato or does it correspond to a [**tie**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_(music)), in which case the *c sharp* note is only played in the starting chord but held down during the following chord?

- Finally, what is the general rule in distinguishing between slurs and ties?

Comment: An interesting question - on the 4th and 5th chords, does the E (R.H.) get played once or twice?

Comment: @Tim twice, as there's no direct tie line between them. The double e is actually quite audible, when you listen to the piece, e.g. [here](https://youtu.be/FxibkvfXWIo?t=34s).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A curved line that connects two successive notes that are the same pitch is a tie. If they are different pitches, it is a slur.

In this example, the C sharps in the bottom voices in the right hand are tied, and the other voices are played legato according to the slurs.

Answer (score 4):

As an addendum to [@musarithmia's answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/34103/70803):

The Henle edition contains two versions of this Nocturne: one from a copyist's manuscript, and one from Chopin's autograph (which the editor suggests was a draft version.)<sup>1</sup> In both cases, the tied C#s (that don't cross the bar line) are indicated not as tied notes but rather as dotted quarter-notes.

Here are the first measures from the "Kolberg" copyist's manuscript, which shows the dotted-quarter notation.

[image: Chopin B.49 (KK IVa no. 16), Kolberg copy, mm. 1–4]
(Image source: [Online Chopin Variorum Edition](https://chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/browse/pageview/72861/)

---

<sup>1</sup> Frédéric Chopin. "Nocturnes". ed. Ewald Zimmerman. 1980(?). G. Henle Verlag. See esp. pp. v and 130-31.

Comment: It seems that ties are used to avoid off-beas tied notes.. Both notations are played the same way.

Comment: @ttw Indeed, the point of this answer is that we know they're ties and not slurs because they could have been written this way instead.